# Prosus compra StackOverflow por 1800 millones

Tags: discusión, stackexchange

Como sabrán algunos, [Prosus](https://www.prosus.com/), principal accionista del gigante [Tencent](https://www.google.com/search?q=tencent) puso sobre la mesa 1800 millones de dólares para comprar StackOverflow, y estos últimos correspondieron al cortejo.

**Comunicado** (en inglés)
[Prosus’s Acquisition of Stack Overflow: Our Exciting Next Chapter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/)

**Hilo en Meta** (en ingles)
[What will happen to Stack Overflow now that it has been sold to Prosus for $1.8 Billion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408138/1545868)

Los analistas apuntan a que Prosus estaría más interesado en rentabilizar el servicio de StackOverflow for Teams y dejará tranquilo el resto de la organización; según dijeron, *todo seguirá igual*. Sin embargo a mediano-largo plazo no es raro que ocurran cambios, espero sean positivos. ¿Qué dicen ustedes?

Comment: Sería interesante si alguien monetizara a todos los que hacemos aportes a stackoverflow

Comment: Mientras no termine SE en medio de líos por lo que está o no está permitido dentro y fuera del Gran Firewall Chino... (que es lo que espero que pase).