# Huelga de moderación en la red de Stack Exchange

Tags: discusión

A partir de hoy, dia 05/06/2023, varios moderadores y usuarios de la red de Stack Exchange han iniciado una huelga de moderación para protestar principalmente (además de por otros motivos) por la nueva política de moderación respecto a las respuestas generadas mediante IA que básicamente nos deja a los moderadores de manos atadas para atajar el problema.

[Aqui (en inglés)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/what-is-the-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content/389583#389583) tenéis una explicación de la nueva política que se nos pide aplicar, y que consiste efectivamente en no hacer nada a no ser que el usuario que publica una respuesta generada por IA admita libremente haberla utilizado.

[Aqui (tambien en inglés, lo siento)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/346768) hay una explicación mas extensa de los motivos de la huelga, y [aqui](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) la carta abierta al Stack Exchange Inc con los motivos tambien y la firma de los usuarios que apoyan la huelga.

Aprovecho esta publicación para comunicar que yo personalmente soy uno de los moderadores que me uno a esta huelga, esperando que la compañía nos escuche dado que solo queremos que el sitio siga siendo una referencia en calidad.

Moderadores que se han plegado de nuestro sitio:

- Pikoh
- Gbianchi

En nuestro caso, se agrega también que no se hará ningún tipo de traducción o aprobación de las mismas.

---

Al dia de hoy, 6/8, por lo menos por mi parte retomo las actividades normales.

Gbianchi

---

A dia 8/8 retomo tambien mis labores de moderación.

Pikoh

Comment: Me sumo a la medida: no moderar, votar ni responder.

Comment: Como usuario que siempre ha demostrado un compromiso real con Stack Overflow en Español, me uno también a esta huelga. De hecho, ya hace algún tiempo he reducido mi participación en el sitio por causas relacionadas a *CheatGPT*, y los vivos tontos que siempre quieren hacer trampa. Por lo tanto apoyo completamente esta iniciativa.

Comment: Siempre he tenido la duda si la red SE fue uno de los principales contribuidores para que chatGPT obtuviese toda la información del ámbito informático y de los otros ámbitos en los que la red SE tiene sitios. Lo leí en varias paginas y reportes, incluso lo decía en Wikipedia en el concepto de chatGPT-3 y lo mencionan [acá](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38660/was-chatgpt-trained-on-stack-overflow-data) también.

Comment: "Huelga de moderación" hahaha!

Comment: Hace tiempo que estoy bastante desconectado de SE por antiguas decisiones de dudosa moralidad que se tomaron por parte del sitio, pero sumo una firma a la causa, por mi parte ya hacia tiempo que dejé de "moderar" el sitio, ahora con más razones.

Comment: De hecho si @OCHOA. No estoy en contra de la IA, al contrario. Lo que no me gusta es el rumbo que ha tomado OpenAI y sus productos. Una compañía que cada vez hace más énfasis en sus herramientas comerciales entrenadas por ti, por mi y millones de desarrolladores, artistas, científicos, etc, sin pedir permiso y en muchos casos violando propiedad intelectual. Algo similar a la polémica Copilot - GitHub. Y volvemos al problema del ser humano: unos pocos se creen con el derecho de tomar el trabajo de muchos para llenarse los bolsillos.

Comment: Como lo que pasa en la red SE @aeportugal. Quiero que sepan que apoyo este movimiento pero me gusta ser imparcial. SE fue parte del crecimiento de chatGPT y todos sabemos que no se hizo solo "por amor al arte". Y concuerdo con el sentir de todos, luego que una causa propiciado por la fuerza de la voluntad coge fuerza y valor monetario, es horrible ver como esa causa se comercializa, se profana. Espero que todo termine en buenos términos aunque la experiencia me dice que no lo hará y que lo más probable (y tomen captura de este comment) de todo esto resurja algo, si es que no existe ya.

Comment: Se requieren elecciones de nuevos moderadores, con una mente un poco mas abierta ...

Comment: Siempre lo he dicho, para decir que todo lo que da una I.A es un plagio… primero tenemos que decir que todo lo que aprendemos nosotros alguien lo invento antes y lo estamos plagiando….

Comment: Una IA reproduce respuestas basadas en todo lo que se le enseñe a partir de bases de datos de todo tipo… asumiendo que sean bases de datos públicas o privadas, la I.A intenta dar respuestas orientadas a la pregunta del usuario…

Comment: No es lo mismo preguntarle a la I.A: dame un ejemplo de un código que haga: esto, esto, esto…
A preguntarle por: dame el código que hizo fulanito de tal….

Comment: El problema no es la I.A el problema es la adaptabilidad de los sitios y las personas a este nuevo ritmo, porque si, aquí lo que lesiona el funcionamiento correcto de los sitios de Q&A es el ritmo en el que cae la preguntas y respuestas relacionado al tiempo respuesta de la moderación...

Comment: Mientras sigan pensando dentro de la caja … en esa área de confort … dirán que las preguntas o respuesta de la I.A. son de baja calidad o son un plagio, para mi opinión son escusas baratas …

Comment: Quien no esté de acuerdo puede renunciar a su cargo de moderador. Y ahora más que SE fue comprado por MS y MS cree rotundamente en la implementación de las I.A como medio para la aceleración en la gestión de productos.

Comment: Ahora la realidad; debido a la toxicidad de la comunidad de sitios como SO y SOes, muchas personas prefieren ir a chat GPT y preguntar cómo se hace XYZ cosa; en pocas palabras es más fácil lidiar con un pront que lidiar con un grupo de personas que simplemente te descatalogan como usuario y como pregunta sin dejar algo que te oriente en los comentarios… esto trascendió y esas mismas personas… han pasado a dar respuesta de chat-GPT por las personas que publican aquí… las respuestas son del estilo AS-IS … sin verificación/validación …

Comment: En la media que chat GPT mejore sus respuestas, y lo usuarios aprendan a hacer mejor sus preguntas a la IA/pront, se irá perdiendo la pista de que es de chat GPT y que es de un usuario.

Comment: Esta es una guerra, que a largo plazo ganara la I.A … por que las I.A pueden mejorar… sin embargo la moderación seguirá estancada tanto en razonamiento como en volumen de trabajo.

Comment: La dirección correcta que debe tomar la moderación del sitio es un punto intermedio y determinar que respuestas son correctas e incorrecta tal cual si se tratase de un usuario… permitir que los usuarios marquen sus respuestas como “respuesta dada de una I.A.” y bloquear cualquier cambio de reputación que gane el usuario de votos positivos o negativos, como si se tratase de una pregunta/respuesta estilo Wiki o de Comunidad.

Comment: La calidad de la preguntas/respuesta sigue siendo responsabilidad de aquellos usuarios que tanto alegan que la prioridad es la calidad, la única diferencia es que sistemáticamente necesitaríamos una cola para evaluar las preguntas que tiene como origen una I.A. eliminar cualquier restricción y agregar medallas nuevas orientadas a este nuevo paradigma.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390165/the-role-of-ai-in-question-and-answer-sites-addressing-concerns-of-plagiarism-a

Comment: Todo mi apoyo a los moderadores, la pasión y la dedicación requeridas para ofrecer información de forma altruista durante todo el tiempo que han sido parte de la comunidad tienen mas peso para mi que cualquier otra cosa, son gente que literalmente ha regalado su tiempo a todos nosotros, en la medida que pueda apoyarlos, que cuenten conmigo

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 "Se requieren elecciones de nuevos moderadores, con una mente un poco mas abierta..", no se trata de tener la mente mas abierta o no, este sitio ha nacido y crecido con la intención de proporcionar una base de conocimientos de calidad, en el momento que se mete gente poniendo respuestas de una IA (las cuales, muchas de ellas seran incorrectas) el sitio pierde la calidad por la cual se ha estado luchando muchos años, y se tira por la borda todo el trabajo hecho para conservar ese objetivo. Creo que el que tiene que entender la situación eres tu antes que criticar a los demás.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Con respecto a lo de la toxicidad en SO en general, tu lo vees como toxicidad, todos los que llevamos tiempo y sabemos las normas lo vemos como moderación del sitio, si alguien hace una pregunta de baja calidad, la pregunta se cierra, esto ha sido así siempre, si no te gusta, puedes irte cuando quieras

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 no entendiste absolutamente nada de porque es la huelga.. yo que vos, pregunto antes de decir todas esas cosas...

Comment: [@ArcanisGK507] Yo veo una mala moderación, pero no toxicidad. Cambiar moderadores diamantados no cambiará a la comunidad.
Tenemos suerte de que aquí se haya debatido. En una red social común, proponer lo mismo con los dislikes resultaría en desacuerdo. Sin embargo, estoy de acuerdo con que todo dislike y su variante sea explicada.
Sobre tu propuesta ¿la moderación daría abasto para moderar a tantas respuestas de ia? La problematica a trabajar por la comunidad debería (no se si es así) ser la pregunta que planteé y la idea de que una persona que viene a SO no busca una respuesta de ChatGPT.

Comment: [@Marc] Si hubieses leido cada comentario, probablemente hubieses considerado que la propuesta de Arkanis es justamente moderar las respuestas como si fueran respuestas "normales", así solucionandose el problema. Aunque esto actualmente podría ser dificil debido a la cantidad de respuestas de IA. No son muchos los que saben las normas, o que las hacen cumplir el 100% de las veces. Sea el motivo que sea, la moderación del sitio está algo descarrilada.

Comment: [@gbianchi-enhuelga] El no hablaba de la huelga, se estaba quejando, justificadamente, de la situación del sitio, tema que salió del desencadenante de la huelga.

Comment: Nunca he sido moderador profesional, pero os acompaño en el sentimiento. Voy a leerme de qué va todo esto...

Comment: Apoyo vuestra causa... aunque nunca haya sido moderador (tener ciertos privilegios de moderación no cuenta)... aunque ya desista de seguir siendo parte de StackOverflow o cualquiera de sus variantes. Yo ya perdí la esperanza y la fe en esta comunidad... por lo cual quiero eliminar todas mis cuentas de StackExchange. 8 años acumulando "reputación" (que tampoco es tanta) ya no significan nada para mí.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Que Microsoft ha comprado StackExchange??? Es EN SERIO?? *+€(#! :furia_porcina:  Otro motivo más para querer borrar todas mis cuentas de StackExchange

Comment: @SebasSBM Stack Overflow, y posiblemente Stack Exchange, fue [adquirido en 2021](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5122/80870) por una compañía llamada [Prosus](https://www.prosus.com/our-portfolio). Posiblemente el compañero se habrá referido a la compra de GitHub por parte de Microsoft.

Comment: @aeportugal Ahh, ya veo... Que GitHub es de Microsoft???? *+€(#! :furia_porcina: 

Comment: Desde hace un tiempo he usado Stack Overflow para preguntarle a la comunidad ciertas cosas y en un principio mis preguntas fueron totalmente rechazadas, ¿por qué? pues simplemente porque no tenían calidad y no estaban bien formuladas. En cierta medida eso ayuda al usuario a mejorar en su calidad de planteamiento y de razonamiento. Por otro lado, muchas veces trataba de evitar preguntar cosas tan simples que no estaban en el sitio, referentes a macros, y prefería no preguntar, pero para mejorar la comunidad planteaba la pregunta y finalmente yo mismo terminaba respondiendo con calidad

Comment: Sí que es cierto que para mí hubiera sido más simple preguntarle a una I.A., en ese momento, antes de que GPT se lanzara. Esto debido a que la comunidad te descartaba por una pregunta repetitiva. Para la mayoría de los usuarios, las preguntas que existen en la comunidad son genéricas, y es más fácil preguntarle a la I.A., una cosa específica que pasar un mal rato recibiendo críticas en la comunidad. De ahí el fenómeno por el que GPT está ganando terreno.

Comment: Quizá suene tonto, pero no pierdo nada con decirlo, propondría crear una separación en donde se permita repuestas de tipo ChatGPT y respuestas exclusivas de la comunidad. Si has venido a este sitio es porque no quieres GPT, pero quizá existan personas que no saben plantear correctamente sus respuestas y por la comodidad, pedirían ayuda a un voluntario para que planté la pregunta de la mejor manera a GPT

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez Es que no hay magia en el asunto, si no puedes proporcionar una buena pregunta a ChatGPT es aun menos probable que puedas generar una pregunta aceptable en este sitio.  Además sobran las personas con ganas de responder y si tu pregunta es clara, acotada y tiene todos los ingredientes necesarios seguramente obtendrás mas de una respuesta en minutos

Comment: @Yussef, aunque te cueste admitirlo Chat GPT y otro tipo de IA llegaron para quedarse, te guste o no. Se tendrá que adaptar la forma de preguntar y esperar respuestas, para ello hay que ser muy específico qué clase de respuestas queremos, si hechas por un humano o una IA. Tan solo mira a GPT 4, no hay manera de competir contra eso.

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez por qué me va a costar admitirlo? Te fuiste por otro lado en tu comentario, pero te respondo igualmente. Nadie prohíbe usar Chatgpt, úsalo como y cuando quieras, pero no en el sitio. Nadie te prohíbe usar un automóvil, pero no lo uses en una carrera de bieletas, simplemente no es el lugar. Y es que hay buenas razones para ello: (1) Hoy ChatGPT no da buenas respuesta, es que a mi ni la mitad de lo que pregunto lo responde correctamente, pero su verborrea dificulta apreciar el error, esto hace difícil moderar las respuestas

Comment: @Yussef, existe una huelga en la que se han propuesto soluciones como la mía. Hacer secciones para un tipo de respuesta en específico, ya sea que lo genere una máquina o un humano. Me di cuenta que mi propuesta no es original y otras personas piensan en una propuesta muy similar a la mía. Por lo tanto, tu analogía de usar un auto en una autopista y no en el carril de bicicletas tendría sentido si no fuera un tema tan complejo como la comunicación de un tema del emisor al receptor. Y sí, concuerdo contigo, GPT 3.5 da respuestas de mala calidad y muchas veces erráticas

Comment: (2) Tu lo dijiste la IA llegó para quedarse, por esa misma razón es necesario contar con un repositorio de conocimiento generado por humanos, para que la evolución de la IA no se estanque por endogamia. (3) La gamificación del sitio atrae a desarrolladores, si tu los pones a competir contra la IA se pierde un gran incentivo, por lo que hace peligrar el sitio, y cuando ya no exista SO y el chatgpt comience a cobrar 5USD la pregunta vamos a quedar peor.

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez Sé que hay propuestas similares, pasa que no estoy de acuerdo. El que quiera una respuesta de la IA que vaya y pregunte directamente, el que quiera una de humanos pregunte en SO.

Comment: @Yussef, GPT 4 es más avanzado que GPT 3.5. Esto seguirá avanzando y la IA será cada vez más capaz. ¿Por qué tendría que existir un incentivo? Los colaboradores estan aquí por mero gusto, no para recivir un incentivo a cambio. Finalmente, GPT 4 es de pago, las personas que quieran dar respuestas a las preguntas, en una sección hipotética de respuestas por IA, podrían usar gratuitamente su cuenta de pago para responder dichas preguntas que los usuarios no pueden pagar.

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez Vuelvo a discrepar, el incentivo de los puntos existe es innegable y parte central del sistema SO. Casi toda la operación se basa en cuantos puntos has ganado. Sobre lo otro: nada te asegura que el que responda lo haga con la versión 4, perfectamente lo puede hacer con la 3.5 que le sale gratis, pero luego quien revisa esa cantidad de respuestas?? Es que creo que tu no estuviste presente cuando recién apareció chagpt era imposible moderar todas las respuestas, porque además suenan convincentes

Answer (score 12):

[Traducción post [Moderation strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an), primera parte]

**Introducción**

Hoy, 5 de junio de 2023, numerosos moderadores, curadores, contribuidores y usuarios de Stack Overflow y Stack Exchange estamos iniciando un paro general de moderación. Esto es en protesta a cambios recientes y otros previstos realizados por la empresa en la plataforma y políticas.

Hemos publicado una carta abierta en la que detallamos las acciones a evitar, las preocupaciones de los firmantes, y las acciones concretas que la empresa debe tomar para resolver la situación. Los miembros en paro se abstendrán de moderar y curar contenidos, incluyendo alertas.

Sin embargo, la carta no contiene todas nuestras preocupaciones, y creemos importante compartir detalles y trasfondo no incluidos en la carta por razones de brevedad. También queremos tratar varios puntos directamente relaciones con la conducta de la empresa.

**Trasfondo**

**Una historia de la política sobre Inteligencia Artificial.**

El 5/12/22, los moderadores formularon una "política temporal" prohibiendo el uso de ChatGPT en particular para este sitio. La razón fue la imprecisión general de las respuestas, y la violación de las normas sobre referencias en Stack Overflow. Los moderadores se retroalimentan de la comunidad, que apoya estas medidas, similares a las instauradas a través de la red.

En cosa de días, miles de publicaciones fueron removidas y cientos de usuarios suspendidos por violar está política.

Durante los meses siguientes, el staff de la empresa colaboró para imponer estas políticas. Esto incluyó agregar un banner al sitio anunciando la prohibición y también editar los artículos del Centro de Ayuda para mencionar la política. Los moderadores también tuvieron permiso para suspender por 30 días las cuentas en violación, saltándose el proceso de escalación regular.

El 29 de mayo de 2023 (feriado importante en USA, California, Reino Unido, y posiblemente otros lugares), un CM publicó un post en Team2, un sitio restringido para moderadores.

Con una breve mención a "detectores de GPT", el post discute la tasa de errores experimentados por detectores automáticos para la detección de IA, específicamente GPT, algo que los moderadores tienen bien presente y considerado.

La publicación sigue exigiendo el cese inmediato de suspensiones relacionadas con contenido generado por IA y el cese de moderación basado en este sólo aspecto, dejando una única causa válida, un caso excepcionalmente raro, para suspender o eliminar dicho contenido. Esto cayó bastante mal entre los moderadores, preocupados por el daño que esto conlleva.

El 30 de mayo, 2023, se publicó una versión de la política en Meta Stack Exchange etiquetada como *mod-agreement-policy*, lo que la hace obligatoria para los moderadores. Esta política difiere sustancialmente de la entregada en privada a los moderadores. En particular, la versión pública excluye los "requerimientos" hechos en privado para prácticamente cesar de inmediato toda moderación de contenidos IA.

La nueva política que hace el contenido IA *de facto* permitido en la red es dañino, por lo que permite en la plataforma y como está implementado.

La nueva política pasa a llevar el consenso previo de la comunidad, de los moderadores, y no fue discutida con ningún miembro de la comunidad. Fue presentada fraudulentamente a los moderadores, y en forma aún más falsa al público, y se basa en afirmaciones sin base, derivadas de un análisis de datos sin revisión ni validación.

Se espera que los moderadores impongan esta política como se escribió en privado, pero sin la posibilidad de compartir sus detalles específicos en aquello que difieren de la versión pública.

Además de los problemas por como la empresa implementó los cambios, estos tienen ramificaciones directas y perjudiciales para la plataforma. Muchos creen firmemente que permitir contenidos generados por IA llevara a cero el valor del sitio con el tiempo.

[Continuará ...]

Answer (score 10):

[Parte 2 y final]

**Serias fallas de comunicación**

Ha habido una consistente falla de comunicación por parte de la empresa en el proceso de crear, anunciar e implementar la nueva política. Ha faltado comunicación con los moderadores y con la comunicación. Cuando hay comunicación, es sólo en un sentido, y la empresa se resiste a recibir retroalimentación crítica.

Philippe, *Vice President of Community*, ofreció unba discusión en el chat privado *Teachers’ Lounge* (sólo moderadores), lo que tomó días para realizarse. Se abordaron ciertas preocupaciones, pero las preguntas difíciles siguen sin respuesta, particularmente la falta de comunicación oportuna.

**El problema con contenido generado por IA**

Se ha hablado del tema hasta el cansancio, tanto en Stack Exchange como en el resto del mundo, pero sentimos que es importante destacar unas pocas razones por las que varias comunidades (no sólo Stack Overflow) decidieron prohibir IA. Estas razones justifican no sólo nuestra posición en contra de IA; también explican como nos sentimos confundidos y traicionados por la súbita decisión de la empresa de parar nuestros esfuerzos por implementar una política apoyada por la comunidad.

Citando al moderador Machavity, los chatbots de IA son como loros. ChatGPT, por ejemplo, no comprende las respuestas que entrega; simplemente asocia el prompt dado con información previa y regurgita frases de aspecto plausible. No tiene manera de verificar la exactitud de las respuestas. ChatGPT no es un escritor, programador, científico, físico ni ningún tipo de experto de los que aportan contenido de valor a nuestros sitios.

Cuando se le pregunta, simplemente concatena palabras según la información con que fue entrenado. No entiende lo que dice. Esta falta de comprensión presenta la información no verificada en una manera que suena inteligente o agregando citas que no respaldan sus afirmaciones (suponiendo que son reales para empezar). Peor, la facilidad con que el usuario puede cortar y pegar el contenido de una respuesta IA simplemente mueve el "loro" del chatbot al usuario. El usuario no entiende realmente lo que copia y lo presenta como respuesta a la pregunta.

Los contenidos publicados sin comprensión innata del dominio, pero escritos de modo "inteligente", son peligrosos para la integridad de la misión de Stack Exchange: ser un repositorio de preguntas-respuestas de alta calidad.

Las respuestas generadas por IA también representan un serio problema de honestidad. Publicar respuestas generadas por IA sin atribución de la fuente, lo que es común, es plagio. Esto hace el contenido generado por IA elegible para eliminar de acuerdo con el código de conducta y las reglas sobre referencias del sitio. Sin embargo, para que un moderador pueda actuar, deben identificarla como generada por IA siguiendo las políticas privadas de la empresa, las que capturan un muy bajo porcentaje de los casos.

**No es sólo la nueva política de IA**

El foco principal de la huelga es la potencial pérdida total de valor del sitio debido a los contenidos generados por IA. Sin embargo, también es acerca del reciente patrón de conducta de la empresa.

La empresa nuevamente ignora las necesidades y consenso establecido de la comunidad, enfocándose, en cambio, en sus objetivos comerciales a expensas de los Community Managers. Las peticiones de herramientas y mejoras a la experiencia de usuario son postergadas. Por ejemplo, el chat, una de las herramientas esenciales para moderadores y curadores, está obsoleto, mientras valiosos cambios que requieren sólo dos minutos de trabajo son ignorados por años.

Más aún, la empresa repetidamente anuncia cambios que los moderadores estiman causan directo daño a los objetivos de la plataforma (esta política sobre IA entre ellas). No se consultó a la comunidad, ni a los moderadores, ni a la base general sobre estos cambios, presentados como hechos consumados.

Se ha frenado algunos cambios debido a la controversia (esta huelga ayuda), pero no desmiente la tendencia de la empresa a tomar decisiones que afectan la esencia misma del sitio sin consultar a los más afectados.

Los eventos de las últimas semanas son la historia que se repite. La empresa emprende nuevos proyectos, IA generativa esta vez, en contraste con los intereses de la comunidad, toma decisiones a contrapelo de la opinión general, corta sus comunicaciones con nosotros y nosotros nos declaramos en huelga. Es similar a lo acontecido la última vez que preparamos una huelga.

**Como resolver esto**

Aunque la huelga puede terminar, muchos miembros de la comunidad no están cómodos con el retorno a la situación previa a la política IA misma, si nada más cambia. El foco de la huelga en IA no ignora las otras acciones de la empresa. Demandamos más que la simple retracción de la política IA. Las promesas que la empresa hizo luego de la debacle del 2019 no se cumplieron. Nos preocupa que vuelva a pasar lo mismo.

Aunque las recientes acciones de la empresa están en conflicto con la comunidad y son un retroceso significativo en las relaciones con la comunidad, no creemos que el quiebre sea irreparable. Nos preocupa, en cambio, estar cerca del punto donde ya no haya más arreglos posibles.

Puede ser cierto que la empresa quiere atender nuestras necesidades y que se preocupa por nosotros, pero la realidad es que no es así. Es tiempo de despertar y reconocer la realidad: la empresa no está trabajando por nuestros intereses. Es tiempo de que lo haga.

**El petitorio**

Se deben satisfacer las siguientes condiciones para terminar la huelga:

- Cancelar la política IA y reformularla de acuerdo con las preocupaciones planteadas. Dar poder a los moderadores para imponer las políticas de prohibición de contenidos generados por IA.
- Informar a la comunidad de las políticas de IA dadas directamente a los moderadores. El hecho que la empresa dice una cosa en privado y otra significativamente diferente en público, pone a los moderadores en aprietos y se arriesgan a ser acusados de irracionales. La empresa ha perjudicado a los moderadores con sus nuevas políticas. La empresa debe reconocerlo.
- Una comunicación clara y abierta con la empresa en lo relativo a establecer/cambiar políticas o componentes importantes, con discusión pública abierta y amplia.
- Comunicaciones claras y honestas de la empresa acerca del futuro del sitio.
- Colaborar con la comunidad en lugar de pelear con ella.
- Terminar con la deshonestidad en las relaciones de la empresa con la comunidad.

**Un cambio en la filosofía del liderazgo de la comunidad**

Necesitamos que los líderes de la empresa interactúen con los miembros y administradores de la comunidad, porque parece que actualmente los ignoran.

Parece que las preocupaciones financieras determinan el desarrollo de nuevas funcionalidades. La comunidad también desea nuevos desarrollos para sus necesidades, pero no se le presta atención ni se le destinan recursos. La falta de consideración de la empresa con la comunidad y administradores significa que sus decisiones de negocios son desenfrenadas y dañinas (como la política IA).

La empresa necesita cambiar su filosofía por una que trate a la comunidad como algo más que un producto, y que valorice sus necesidades y experiencia. Es obvio que esa no es la filosofía actual, y que la empresa toma por dado la experiencia en su propio producto. La empresa debe responder asignando recursos según las necesidades de la comunidad y las suyas propias, y guiando el desarrollo con la experiencia de la comunidad.

**Conclusión**

Los sitios de Stack Exchange corren sin problemas gracias a incontables horas de trabajo voluntario no remunerado, y, en algunos casos, a proyectos pagados por la misma comunidad. La empresa debe recordar que descuidar y maltratar a sus voluntarios sólo conducirá a menos buena voluntad y motivación por quienes contribuyen a la plataforma.

Mantendremos una huelga general de moderación hasta que los problemas señalados en esta publicación sean resueltos. Moderadores, curadores, contribuidores y usuarios: los invitamos a firmar esta carta y adherir a la huelga.

Comment: Muchas gracias por dedicar el tiempo a traducir la publicación original :)

Comment: "la empresa no está trabajando por nuestros intereses"
Desde cuando una empresa trabaja por los intereses de otros? Si se llenan de plata con gente que TRABAJA GRATIS, al menos, deberían tomarse el tiempo de escuchar a la comunidad que los sostiene.

Answer (score 3):

[Las negociaciones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390704/1380861) entre los representantes de la comunidad y los representantes de Stack Exchange han culminado.

### Resumen de los acuerdos logrados

[Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/1380861) (Original - En Inglés)

[Huelga de moderación: resultado de las negociaciones](https://meta-stackexchange-com.translate.goog/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es-419&_x_tr_pto=wapp) (Español - Traducción Automática)

En un principio pensé traducir todo el artículo, pero creo sería demasiado largo para muchos (y tiempo no me sobra), así que esto es producto de una **traducción automática** y luego un resumen de todos los puntos (sin IA, por supuesto (jeje)) para que sea menos pesado. Si alguien considera se debe mejorar o ampliar algo, sírvase en editarlo libremente.

---

## Publicaciones generadas por IA

### Reemplazar la política de "autoadmisión" y permitir la moderación de publicaciones generadas por IA

Stack Exchange acordó permitir la eliminación de contenido en función de un solo indicador fuerte de uso de GPT, o de varios indicadores más débiles. Con vigencia inmediata, los estándares provisionales que hemos acordado servirán como política hasta que se establezca una política más permanente con la ayuda de la comunidad en general, incluida la determinación de heurísticas adicionales.

### Liberación de la "política de autoadmisión" privada

Stack Exchange, Inc. ha lanzado la versión anterior privada de la política que restringe la moderación en el contenido generado por IA. Esta política ya no está en vigor. Ver [Política (Histórica) sobre el uso de detectores GPT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391626/).

### Probar las capacidades de los moderadores para detectar contenido generado por IA

El equipo de investigación de Stack Exchange, Inc. está desarrollando un proceso para probar las capacidades de los moderadores de la red de Stack Exchange para detectar contenido generado por IA.

## Los volcados de datos (dumps), el Explorador de datos de Stack Exchange y la API de Stack Exchange

Stack Exchange, Inc. ha publicado un compromiso público de mantener y proporcionar estos servicios de forma gratuita en beneficio de la comunidad. Ver [Compromiso de la empresa con los volcados de datos, la API y la SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391634/).

## Cambios al Acuerdo del Moderador

### Un período de revisión obligatorio para las políticas vinculantes

Cualquier política vinculante propuesta para toda la red debe someterse a un período obligatorio de retroalimentación y revisión, de un mínimo de siete días hábiles, donde los moderadores de la red de Stack Exchange pueden proporcionar comentarios y tener la política revisado antes de que se publique.

### Stack Exchange, Inc. no puede ordenar que se tomen medidas de moderación sin una política pública que las respalde.

El personal de Stack Exchange, Inc., incluidos los administradores de la comunidad, no puede exigir que se tomen medidas que afecten a los usuarios que no son moderadores sin una política pública que establezca que se deben tomar estas medidas.

### Orientación privada durante el proceso de revisión de la conducta del moderador

Se puede emitir orientación privada durante el proceso de revisión de la conducta del moderador que se aplica solo a ese moderador individual. Esto aún está sujeto a la restricción de que no puede exigir acciones que afecten a los usuarios que no son moderadores, y el moderador en cuestión aún puede optar por revelar la orientación que recibió, ya sea a sus compañeros moderadores o públicamente.

### Actualización de la Política de prensa en torno a las declaraciones sobre moderación

A la luz de los comentarios enviados a la prensa por Stack Exchange Inc. en respuesta a la huelga, el Acuerdo del Moderador se actualizará para reflejar más restricciones sobre dichos comentarios. En el futuro, cualquier comentario que se haga a la prensa que implique moderación deberá pasar por la aprobación de al menos un miembro del [Community Management Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341), ya que en este caso no sucedió.

### Determinar si Stack Exchange, Inc. violó el Acuerdo del Moderador

A partir de la [versión V2 del Acuerdo del Moderador](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement/versions/2), no existe ninguna disposición para determinar si Stack Exchange, Inc. violó el Acuerdo del Moderador. Existe un proceso para [determinar si un moderador violó el Acuerdo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336178/), así como un proceso para que los moderadores [determinen si se debe eliminar a otro moderador](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336174/), pero no hay un proceso para determinar si la empresa violó el acuerdo.

En caso de que se determine que Stack Exchange, Inc. ha violado el Acuerdo de Moderador, Stack Exchange, Inc. debe:

- Retractarse y anular cualquier acción o comentario realizado durante
  el curso de la violación; y
- Emita una disculpa pública a Meta Stack Exchange detallando la violación cometida.

### Comentarios estándar y período de revisión para los cambios en el Acuerdo del Moderador en sí

Cualquier cambio al Acuerdo del Moderador mencionado aquí aún está sujeto al período estándar de retroalimentación y revisión para los cambios al Acuerdo del Moderador. Se requiere un mínimo de 30 días para comentarios y revisiones antes de que los cambios entren en vigor.

## Cambios en los procesos internos de Stack Exchange, Inc.

### Comunicarse con los moderadores en casos poco claros

Descubrimos una gran desconexión en las expectativas en torno al personal de Stack Exchange que revisa las acciones realizadas por los moderadores voluntarios. Si un usuario enviaba una queja a través del formulario de contacto sobre una acción del moderador, la política interna de Stack Exchange dictaba que el personal no debería comunicarse con el moderador que tomó esa acción para pedirle que justifique por qué se tomó esa acción.

Los moderadores son humanos y cometen errores. La expectativa es que el personal investigue cuando se le contacte sobre posibles errores del moderador, investigando el asunto por sí mismo y luego, si aún no está claro para el personal lo que sucedió, discutirá con el moderador que tomó medidas. Si el resultado final es que el moderador cometió un error, eso debe detectarse y las quejas sobre el error del moderador no deben descartarse automáticamente.

### No realizar cambios irreversibles en la plataforma.

Se hizo un anuncio al Equipo de moderadores, indicando que se estaba realizando un cambio importante en un sistema fundamental de la plataforma y que este cambio se aplicaría en toda la red y de manera irrevocable. Ese cambio se detuvo temporalmente poco antes de la huelga mientras se reevaluaba el impacto, se investigaban las mitigaciones y los posibles ajustes. Desde entonces se ha aclarado que este no será un cambio irreversible y que fue una suposición errónea por parte de la persona que publicó el anuncio.

### Compromiso con la transparencia

El personal de Stack Exchange, Inc. será lo más transparente posible sobre el desarrollo y la política de productos, y compartirá regularmente las actualizaciones y los cambios propuestos. Los lanzamientos se comunicarán de manera oportuna.

### Teniendo en cuenta los comentarios de la comunidad

El personal trabajará con la comunidad al tomar decisiones sobre el desarrollo y la política de productos, teniendo en cuenta los comentarios y sugerencias de la comunidad, al mismo tiempo que considera otros puntos de datos e investigaciones.

## Cambios en la plataforma de Stack Exchange

### Notificar a los usuarios sobre las políticas en torno al contenido generado por IA

Los datos recopilados por los moderadores de Stack Overflow indican que un porcentaje significativo de usuarios que fueron suspendidos o advertidos por publicar contenido generado por IA no estaban al tanto de la prohibición de publicar dicho contenido. Stack Exchange, Inc. implementará una advertencia que mostrará a los usuarios que pegan contenido en el cuadro de respuesta, notificando al usuario sobre la prohibición del contenido generado por IA y, con suerte, disminuyendo la cantidad de usuarios que desconocen la política.

El texto del aviso a los usuarios se podrá personalizar según el sitio y se podrá habilitar/deshabilitar según el sitio. El trabajo inicial en esto ha comenzado. A los moderadores de Stack Overflow se les ha entregado recientemente una maqueta de un primer concepto y se han solicitado sus comentarios.

### Herramientas para la comunicación con los Moderadores y determinar si la empresa violó el Acuerdo de Moderadores

Stack Exchange, Inc. se compromete a desarrollar e implementar herramientas para que los moderadores se comuniquen y voten si la empresa violó el Acuerdo de moderador. Estas herramientas se desarrollarán en conjunto con los moderadores y junto con la discusión sobre los números necesarios para el proceso. Stack Exchange, Inc. no obstaculizará ni obstruirá de ninguna manera la discusión sobre el asunto de Stack Exchange, Inc. que viola el Acuerdo de Moderador que se lleva a cabo en la plataforma de Stack Exchange.

---

### Conclusión

## ¿Ha terminado la huelga de moderación en Stack Exchange?

Según [esta entrada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391852/1380861) no hay forma de responder **Si** o **No** a esa pregunta, ya que es algo que deben decidir las distintas comunidades (y también los usuarios que participaron en de forma individual), si están conformes con los acuerdos y/o si quieren esperar a ver la evolución de los compromisos de ambas partes.

Comment: Incluso si es automatico, gracias por tomarte la molestia de notificarnos :D

Answer (score -2):

Siempre pensé "si los consumidores lo supieran, podrían tomar control de las desiciones de una empresa". Simplemente, deja de comprarles, y verás como cambian de opinión.

Así que si, aunque no me uno (ya que no modero y considero la moderación definciente), apoyo a los que lo hagan.

---

Cuando en historia te enseñan sobre una guerra, te hablan de desencadenante (la gota que inició todo) y las causas (todas las motivaciones).

Y yo me encuentro que el desencadenante tiene un problema:

La comunidad quiere restringir el uso de ia revisando como escribió la persona. Esto dió falsos positivos, y es indetectable si el usuario modifica el lenguaje usado por chatgpt y reduce la frecuencia de sus respuestas.

La empresa está en contra de los falsos-positivos y quiere que solo la persona que declare explicitamente que usó una ia, sea sancionada. Pero eso es tapar el sol con la mano. Casi no tiene efecto.

Ninguna de las dos son tecnicas muy buenas y no se me ocurre nada mejor. A pesar de eso, me inclino a sacrificar a algunos usuarios honestos que tapar el sol con una mano.